# Place Order Slow in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

When i add product more than 50 in  my cart in magento and place order the cart page place order process tooo slow how i make it fast ??

Comment: With default magento?

Comment: yes checkout/onepage/saveOrder/ function

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: @sdfasdf Still running slow?  We are here to assist.